# How are overridden methods from ReceiverAdapter class such as viewAccepted() method called in jgroups if I have not called them explicitly?

Tags: java, inheritance, jboss, jgroups

I have written the following class to create a JGroup cluster:

```
public class TestClient extends ReceiverAdapter {
JChannel channel;

private void start() throws Exception {
    channel=new JChannel().setReceiver(this);
    channel.connect("ChatCluster");
    eventLoop();
    channel.close();
}

private void eventLoop() {
    while(true) {
    }
}

public void viewAccepted(View new_view) {
    System.out.println("** view: " + new_view);
    System.out.println("Get Coord"+new_view.getCoord());
    System.out.println(new_view.getMembers());
}

public void receive(Message msg) {
    System.out.println(msg.getSrc() + ": " + msg.getObject());

}

public void getState(OutputStream output) throws Exception {

}

public void setState(InputStream input) throws Exception {

}
}
```

ReceiverAdapter is a Jgroups defined class:

```
public class ReceiverAdapter implements Receiver {
public ReceiverAdapter() {
}

public void receive(Message msg) {
}

public void receive(MessageBatch batch) {
    Iterator var2 = batch.iterator();

    while(var2.hasNext()) {
        Message msg = (Message)var2.next();

        try {
            this.receive(msg);
        } catch (Throwable var5) {
            ;
        }
    }

}

public void getState(OutputStream output) throws Exception {
}

public void setState(InputStream input) throws Exception {
}

public void viewAccepted(View view) {
}

public void suspect(Address mbr) {
}

public void block() {
}

public void unblock() {
}
}
```

My question here is how are these methods from ReceiverAdapter class invoked on change of view or sending/receiving messages because I do not need to call those explicitly. Does JGroups has some kind of event listener implemeted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you already solved your problem. You need to explicitly pass your Receiver implementation to the JChannel where you want it used:

```
Receiver receiver = new MyReceiverImplementation();
JChannel jChannel = new JChannel().connect("clusterName").receiver(receiver);
```

JGroups does not automatically look for Receivers to inject.